# Is it possible to restore directory on Ubuntu and backup the files?

Tags: 16.04, repository

I run the following commands accidentally :

```
rm -R /etc/apt

rm -R /var/lib
```

Or could anyone tell me what are the main repository of Ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: With a system that gutted, you're probably best off backing up any important data that are left and reinstalling the system.

Comment: "accidently"? I call that "on purpose".  Backup your data through a live session and re-install.

Comment: What about I copy this file and directory from another Pc with the same system . ? Is it going work ?

Comment: It might. I would though still suggest to backup your data and re-install.

Answer (score 0):

> Or could anyone tell me what are the main repository of Ubuntu

create your own "main" repository list here: [Ubuntu Sources List Generator](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/)

1. Select your **Country** from the drop down list.
2. Select your **Version/Release** from the drop down list.
3. Select the **Branches** you want by clicking on their check boxes. I
   suggest not to select the various *Sources Repositories* unless you
   know you need them.
4. Select the Updates you want by clicking on their check boxes. I
   suggest just choosing *Important Security Updates* and *Recommended
   Updates*
5. Scroll to the bottom of the page and click on the **Generate List**
   button.

The resulting page will give you a list of repositories based on your previous selections.

Comment: You might be able to improve this answer with providing the steps needed in more detail how to replace the files he deleted and maybe even adding screen-shots of different parts to make it a rock solid answer.

Comment: And that also restores the pgp keys? and how about "/var/lib/"?

Comment: *And that also restores the pgp keys? and how about "/var/lib/"?*
No, but it will give a list of Ubuntu repositories which answers the **OR** part of the question